# Got error 'mysql_connect(): Too many connections' on live site

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have an ecommerce website it was working fine  but when I give discounted price then may be there was a lot of traffic which might causes this issue.

The "mysql_connect(): Too many connections" error shows when I visit the site.

I have tried increasing the number of connections but it did not work.

Please help me out on this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Restart the MySql Services

Comment: *"I have an ecommerce website"* - I hope that's secure. Using `mysql_`? *Hm....*

Comment: Try to use other of mysql it will be removed in PHP7 and it's not safe, you should use PDO or mysqli

Comment: We are using Kohana framework and I think it is secure.

Comment: @SyedRehman A reason more to change as it should be quite simple. Just change the driver